# Matching files based on time and day of week of creation/modification

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, stat, filemtime

Is there a suitably Pythonic way of determining if a file was created between particular times on a particular day (or days) of the week - e.g. 09:00 to 17:00 Monday to Friday?

At the moment I have:

```
def IsEligible(filename, between = None, weekdays = None):
    """
    Determines the elgibility of a file for processing based on 
    the date and time it was modified (mtime). 'weekdays' is a list 
    of day numbers (Monday = 0 .. Sunday = 6) or None to indicate ALL
    days of the week. 'between' is a tuple which contains the
    lower and upper limits (as datetime.time objects) of the periods 
    under consideration or None to indicate ALL times of day. 
    """

    modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(filename))

    dow = modified.weekday()
    mtime = modified.time()

    if between is not None:
        earliest = min(between)
        latest   = max(between)
        if mtime < earliest or mtime >= latest:
            return False

    if weekdays is not None and dow not in weekdays:
        return False
    print(filename, modified)
    return True
```

which works fine, but I didn't know if there was something smarter. (I know it's a bit wordy, but hopefully it's more readable that way).

One final thing, I originally used `ctime` rather than `mtime` but it didn't produce the results I was after, and seemed just to return the current time, even though the files hadn't been modified or anything since creation. Under what circumstances does the `ctime` value get reset?

Comment: `ctime` is the creation time and `mtime` is the last time the file was modified, `ctime` never gets reset normally unless you change the attributes of the file. This depends on your operating system or more accurately the filesystem used. A simple google will give you a clue of what the three `atime` / `ctime` and `mtime` does: http://www.linux-faqs.info/general/difference-between-mtime-ctime-and-atime

Comment: Since `datetime`s are comparable, you could reduce your within interval check logic to `earliest, latest = sorted(between)` then `if not (earliest <= mtime <= latest):`. Your checks for `not None` can be simplified to just `if between:` and `if weekdays and dow not in weekdays`.

Comment: @martineau I deliberately kept the "is None" verbose as I think it makes more sense to a casual reader.

Comment: @Torxed I've read up about `ctime` (principally as part of debugging the problem). I don't understand why it wasn't behaving as expected, although `mtime` seems to do the trick admirably.

Comment: For a reminder program I wrote once that did a lot of this sort of thing, so I wrote a generic `Interval` class to represent closed intervals The constructor would automatically sort the two values given (which can be any comparable type) and implemented a `__contains__()` method which allows me to write statements like `if value in interval_instance:`. It also had a `__iter__()` method that would `yield` all the intermediate values within the range. Might be over-kill for what you want to do, but since the class is reusable, might be worth the extra effort.

Comment: @martineau That is a _sweet_ idea. I will try doing that. Thank you.